# I have a 2000 civic hatchback with bad motor

Tags: engine, honda, civic, replacements

I have a 2000 civic hatch with a bad motor by friend gave me a single cam vtec motor with tranny just need some help with what I need for the swap

Comment: If you have the complete car and a new motor, you should have all the major parts you need. As far as tools, you'll need a bunch of sockets and wrenches, notably a 10mm, 12mm, 14mm, and a deep well 17mm for the engine mount bolts, probably some rust-breaker lube for exhaust manifold bolts etc. If you're swapping the intake and exhaust, you'll need new gaskets for those as well. Other than that, there are a bunch of great tutorials on youtube I'd recommend which provide far more details than a post response can.

Comment: You will also need to rent or borrow an engine hoist: https://sunextools.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/5218_3-1.png

Comment: First of all, welcome. Secondly, which Civic do you have? Thirdly, which exact engine model did you get to replace the engine. This is the knowledge you need to start to even contemplate replacing the engine. If the wrong engine, you are just plain out of luck.

Comment: I have a 2000 Honda Civic hatchback dx 1.6 not sure what year is the single cam vtec

Comment: On the side of the vtec engine under where the exhaust manifold is, there should be a flat pad with an alphanumeric code stamped into it. It will *most likely* start with the letter "D" and be either four or five characters long. If you can get that for me, I can tell you a lot more about the engine. The beginning of [this video](https://youtu.be/TOzYjh8psaM) should show you where to find what I'm talking about.